# A prgram that prints the length of a line in C

Tags: c, function, file, line, fclose

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUF_LEN 200
#define LINE_NUMBER 3

int line_len(char* filename, int n)
{
    FILE* f;
    char buf[BUF_LEN];
    int j, i = 0;
    if ((f = fopen(filename, "r"))) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, f);
        for (i = 0; buf[i]; i++) /* find end of buf */ ;
        fclose(f);
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", line_len("test.txt", LINE_NUMBER));
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, the function `line_len` receives the name of the file and the number of line we are interested in. It then opens the file in a read only mode and iterates till reaching the line `n`, through each iteration reading `BUF_LEN-1` characters from the file `f` and storing these characters in `buf`. So when the first for loop breaks, `buf` will contain all the characters of the first `n` lines.

I do not understand the need for the second loop. When does it terminate? 
How does this function work? If at the end of the first for loop `buf` will  contain the characters of the first `n` lines, then how come this function returns the length of the line `n`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you forgotten to write any lines of the code?

Comment: The code actually works, right?

Comment: The first `for` loop adds each character of line n to the buf array. The second `for` loop counts the length of buf array (i) and returns that.

Comment: In the second loop, buf has the n-esime (LINE_NUMBER-esime) line, and this loop will count in 'i' how many char's it have. Remember that every string end's in \0. And that is a kind of 0. So, when buf[i] is \0 (your string is over and 'i' already have how many characters it has) the second loop stops.

Comment: I did not forget @Marievi

Comment: Yes, the code works  @Gabriel Pellegrino

Comment: @chux ahh, that's it, missed that.

Comment: No, there's a ; only in the first one @ Sourav Ghosh

Comment: Would be easier to spot the semicolon if it was before the comment not after on the second loop IMHO

Comment: Thanks. If I understand it well, then in the second loop buf contains the characters of the first n lines. If the second loop terminates as soon as it encounters a '\0', then would not it terminate after reading the first string of the first line? @ Gabriel Pellegrino

Comment: @Tree `buf` after the first loop contains the *last line* (`n`th line) of the file.

Comment: @CoolGuy _Hopefully_ it contains a line of the file.  With a file of less than `n` lines or error `for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) 
               fgets( buf, BUF_LEN, f ); for( i = 0; buf[i]; i++ );` is bordering on UB.

Comment: @chux Agreed. As the answer below says, there should be some more error checking. I'm assuming `LINE_NUMBER` is set to the right value...

Comment: Thanks.  How could I know each line overwrites the previous line, I mean how could I know that the line is not appended to the buffer? Also, if the second loop terminates as soon as it encounters a '\0', then would not it terminate after reading the first string of line n-1 instead of reading the entire line? @Cool Guy

Comment: @Tree `fgets` is called with `buf` which is the same as `&buf[0]` here, the address of the _first_ element of the array `buf`. So, in essence, you tell `fgets` to store the read line into `buf` starting from its first location. This results in overwriting previous data in the array.

Comment: @Tree As for your second doubt, I'm not sure where you got `n - 1` from. Assuming you meant `n`th line, it is because a space is not equal to the NUL-terminator character, i.e, `' ' != '\0'`. And ordinary text files usually do not contain any `\0`s. So, the loop goes up to the end of the string upto the last `\0` which was inserted by `fgets`.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I used n-1 as the index of line n.

Answer (score 5):

> I do not understand the need for the second loop. When does it terminate?

The second loop has `buf[i]` as its loop condition. It will keep executing as long as `buf[i]` is true i.e. non zero. So when it gets to the nul character at the end of the line (added by `fgets()`) the loop will terminate.

> How does this function work?

Simplistically, it reads `n` lines. Each line is put into the buffer overwiriting the previous line. After it's read `n` lines, it counts the characters in the buffer from when it read the nth line.

It's a poor piece of code though. There's no error checking on the `fgets` call and if the nth line has more than 199 characters in it, it will give the wrong answer. In fact, if you consider the length of a line to exclude the line feed, it always gets the wrong answer.

It also returns zero <s>if the file has fewer than `n` lines and</s> if it was unable to open the file. If an error occurs reading a line, it returns an indeterminate number and if it runs off the end of the file, the length of the last line will be returned

An error result would be better in those cases.

Comment: @chux Good catch. On end of file the buffer remains unchanged and is "indeterminate" in case of other errors. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It overwrites it, this makes things a lot clearer. Just two things things though:

1- How could I know each line overwrites the previous line, I mean how could I know that the line is not appended to the buffer?
2- if the second loop terminates as soon as it encounters a '\0', then would not it terminate after reading the first string of line n-1 instead of reading the entire line?

Comment: @Tree Point 1 Read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). Unless it says it appends to the buffer you can always assume it overwrites what was there before.

Comment: @Tree Point 2 There is a tacit assumption that text files do not contain `\0` characters. This is usually a reasonable assumption. I don't think it counts as valid UTF-8, for example. I don't know how `fgets` behaves if it encounters `\0` in a line, but if it did read the whole line up to the `\n` you are right that it would give the wrong answer.

Comment: @JeremyP _null characters_ can exist in UTF-8 files. Now someone might not want to call that a _valid_ text file but there is no C prohibition against it.  `fgets()` treats `'\0'` like any other non-`'\n'` character.  BTW: "if an error occurs reading a line, " `for( i = 0; buf[i]; i++ );` is potential UB.  You are right about "t's a poor piece of code ".

Comment: @chux Another problem is that this does not calculate the length of the line in characters but in bytes. If the encoding is UTF-8, it will only give the right answer if the entire file up to the nth line is in the ASCII subset (excluding nul).

Comment: @chux So a  text file is composed of a stream of strings each of which contains a null terminating character in the end? If so, then how come i will be incremented till the end of the line is reached? it looks like in the second for loop, i will be incremented till the end of the first string of line n is reached, not till the end of the entire line, because the first time a '\0' appears, is within the first string of the text file.

Comment: @Tree `fgets` puts the entire line in the buffer (if the buffer is big enough) including the terminating `\n` and then it puts a `\0` just after the `\n`.

Comment: @JeremyP Thank you. I still don't get it: if a text file is composed of a stream of strings each of which contains a null terminating character in the end, then how come i will be incremented till the end of the line is reached? it looks like in the second for loop, i will be incremented till the end of the first string of line n is reached, not till the end of the entire line, because the first time a '\0' appears, is within the first string of the text file

Comment: @Tree It usually doesn't consist of a stream of strings with nuls at the end. It almost always consists of a stream of non nul characters with `\n` as the line separator (on Unix). It's actually one large string. You can put nuls in a text file, but if you do, lots of C programs will break just like the one above.

Comment: @Tree  Text files typically do not contains C _strings_ (sequence of characters up to an including the `'\0`).  Rather, text files typically contain _lines_  (sequence of characters up to an including the `'\n'`).  `fgets()` reads a _line_, including the `'\n'` and appends a `'\0'` to make `buf[]` a _string_.  Implementation concerns include: variable line count, `'\n'` only lines, long lines, lines at file end without `'\n'`, embedded `'\0'` in the text file, line ending variations,  and file input error.   Welcome to text file processing.

Comment: @chux,JeremyP Thank you for the patience and help! 
Now got it. Text files consist of a bunch of strings with '\n' in the end, usually do not contain '\0', but fgets puts a '\0' just after the '\n' so the second loop terminates there.

Comment: @Tree that's about the size of it.